# how can i get custom resolved values

Tags: actions-on-google

the training phrases contain college subject domain/major like computer science engineering, mechanical engineering, information technology..... etc. i want the resolved values to be

CS for computer science

IT for information technology

Me for mechanical engineering

I am trying to figure this out for an hour ... guide me please.

tried creating a custom entity

[image: SNAP]

//no code

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Actions on Google [Node.js client library](https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/nodejsv2/overview) with a [Dialogflow webhook](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/actions-1/#5), you can call a Javascript function at the start of your intent's fulfillment to disambiguate the user's input from predefined arrays of different terms for the same subject.

Try something like:

```
let subject = "mechanical engineering"

function disambiguate(term){

  let CS = ["CS", "cs", "computer science", "comp sci"]

  let ME = ["ME", "me", "mechanical engineering", "mech eng"]

  let IT = ["IT", "it", "information technology"]

  for(let i = 0; i < CS.length; i++){
    if (term == CS[i]){
      return CS;
    }
  }

  for(let i = 0; i < ME.length; i++){
    if (term == ME[i]){
      return ME;
    }
  }

  for(let i = 0; i < IT.length; i++){
    if (term == IT[i]){
      return IT;
    }
  }    

}

console.log(disambiguate(subject)[0])
```

You can edit or run the above code [on Repl](https://repl.it/repls/ThoseBonyBackup).

If you don't want to do this programmatically, you can add synonyms to a custom entity in the Dialogflow console:

[image: Dialogflow Custom Entity + Synonyms]